# Deleting multiple columns from a Parse Class

Tags: parse-platform

I have accidentally created hundreds of columns in my User class. Can anyone tell me how to easily delete a number of columns? Currently the only way I can delete them is individually through the Parse online interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Schema API to delete columns from your collection, check the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas-modifying-the-schema) for details. A good strategy might be to fetch a list of columns the collection you want to modify has, create a list of columns you want to keep and then delete each column that is not in this list.